# Ограничение времени работы скрипта (set_time_limit не работает)

Tags: php

Вставляю в начало скрипта `set_time_limit(700)` в итоге скрипт выполняется около минуты, далее - 504 еррор.
На локальном сервере все нормально выполняется, только вот на VPS такая проблема. Думаю, какой-то конфиг надо поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

504 отдает апач. Гляньте логи (`error.log`) и тогда станет ясно, дело в лимите или какой-то другой конфигурации.